# Developing a Web-Site using Magento Community Edition

Tags: magento-community, custom-product-type, stores

I intend to develop a web-site using Magento Community Edition (free version). The solution needs to have, in addition to an e-commerce store with shopping cart, some other auxiliary web-pages (for example, a page containing some location information) and some pages with hyperlinks that are linked to product information stored in Magento.
I am aware of the Magento's store hierarchy. What is the way in Magento to have such auxiliary web-pages ?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Magento allows you to make as many basic CMS pages as you like.

Comment: We always use https://github.com/ho-nl/magento-clever-cms/

Comment: You can use this to create your custom entities and pages. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html

Comment: I am not sure why this question was closed by  davidalger, Marius, Tim. This is a real question from an industrial environment. Magento CE is the free version of Magento. How to add our own created web page (e.g. test1.html) integrated into Magento ? How can I have a hyperlink in test1.html to be able to retrieve product information of product id 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this link:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/managing-cms-content-pages/

It should give you all the information about making custom pages including linking products, however if you decide along the programatic route, you may need to look into the developers guide:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You could also argue the case, that if you gave them a plain, copy and paste code, that they will not learn why the code works.

Comment: The problem is, that if the site is deleted, the information is lost. And we don't want dead links here :) We want informations. But yes, you are right, so add as much text as possible to explain. I know, this is a big wish :)

Comment: ^ If the database is deleted information is lost, why would the website be deleted?

Comment: Because websites vanish.